# permanently change docker bridge IP

Tags: docker, ipv4

I am trying to configure dockerd to use the bridge ip 172.31.0.1/24 (as i understand it must be a subnet). I configured the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as follows:

```
{   "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]}
{  "bip": "172.31.1.1/24",
  "ipv6": false}
```

Then i did `systemctl stop docker  && systemctl start docker`
It didn't work  :-/
Can you pls help me set up this bridge subnet permanently?
Most help online is on temporary setting, not my interest.

I also changed the file `/etc/default/docker` , but it does not seem to make a difference on systems running on systemd.

Ubuntu 16.04, Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` is not correct right now. Literally it contains two JSON structures inside:

```
{   "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]}
```

and

```
{  "bip": "172.31.1.1/24",
  "ipv6": false}
```

When you start/restart docker on your host it reads JSON structure from `/etc/docker/daemon.json` i.e. only the first part of it. That's why IP changes are not applied.

The correct `/etc/docker/daemon.json` is:

```
{ 
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], 
  "bip": "172.30.1.1/24",
  "ipv6": false
}
```

Comment: It still does not work for me with this new file format. I do not know if docker really reads the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. I really miss a central config file or so.

Comment: What's the result of the `dpkg -l | grep docker` on your host?

Comment: `#ii  docker-ce                                            17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu                          amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine`